# How to Define CountProbation() function using Functions from other Files?

Tags: c++, function

I have been racking my brain on how to properly define the function CountProbation() properly in the Course.css file. I know that a for and if loop should probably be included but I am having trouble including functions from other files, even though I am including a header tag at the beginning of the current Course.css file.

Below are the C++ files that are given in the lab:

NOTE: Only the Course.cpp file is the one that needs to be edited. All of the other files are READ ONLY and purely for your information as the reader.

Sorry if it seems like a lot of code, but I didn't just want to include the Course.cpp file because then you might not understand the program.

**Here are the compiler Errors/Warnings:**

```
Course.cpp: In member function ‘int Course::CountProbation()’:

Course.cpp:8:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<Student>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
    8 |  for (int i=0; i < roster.size(); ++i) {
      |                ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Course.cpp:9:9: error: ‘GetGPA’ was not declared in this scope
    9 |     if (GetGPA() < 2.0) {
      |         ^~~~~~
```

Course.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Course.h"
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int Course::CountProbation() {  //This is the function that I have tried to define as you can see by my 
   int probCount;               //code
   for (int i=1; i < roster.size(); ++i) {
      if (GetGPA() < 2.0) {
         probCount = probCount + 1;
      }
   }
   return probCount;
}

void Course::AddStudent(Student s) {
    roster.push_back(s);
}
```

Course.h (READ ONLY)

```
#ifndef COURSE_H
#define COURSE_H

#include <vector>
#include "Student.h"

class Course {
   public:
      int CountProbation();  
      void AddStudent(Student s);
   
   private:
      vector<Student> roster; //collection of Student objects
};

#endif
```

Main.cpp (READ ONLY)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Course.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
   Course course;
   int probCount;
   
   // Example students for testing
   course.AddStudent(Student("Henry", "Cabot", 3.2));   
   course.AddStudent(Student("Brenda", "Stern", 1.1)); 
   course.AddStudent(Student("Lynda", "Robison", 2.4)); 
   course.AddStudent(Student("Jane", "Flynn", 1.8)); 

    probCount = course.CountProbation();
    cout << "Probation count: " << probCount << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Student.h (READ ONLY)

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Class representing a student
class Student {
   public:
      Student(string first, string last, double gpa);
      double GetGPA() ;
      string GetLast();

   private:
      string first;  // first name
       string last;   // last name
       double gpa;    // grade point average
};

#endif
```

Student.cpp (READ ONLY)

```
#include "Student.h"

// Student class constructor
Student::Student(string first, string last, double gpa) {
        this->first = first;    // first name
        this->last = last;      // last name
        this->gpa = gpa;        // grade point average
}

double Student::GetGPA() {
        return gpa;
}

string Student::GetLast() {
        return last;
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `probCount` to zero, in case there are no students; otherwise the function returns an uninitialized value.

Comment: That briefly looks like a valid C++ code to me. What exactly is your problem with defining the `CountProbation()` function? I see you have some implementation (although iterating over `vector` from 1 instead of 0 is quite odd), and you probably also have some requirements somewhere, but we don't see that.

Comment: In `for (int i=1; i < roster.size(); ++i)` starting `i` at 1 seems a bit odd. usually a loop iterates 0 to the end of the container.

Comment: In `if (Student.GetGPA() < 2.0)`, `Student` is the name of a class, not a variable. You can reuse the name, but A) you probably shouldn't because that just causes confusion and B) I don't see any code that redefines `Student` as an instance of `Student`. You probably want `if (roster[i].GetGPA() < 2.0)` here.

Comment: @yeputons My problem is that, as is shown in Student.h file, each Student object has 3 different variables associated with it. A first name, last name, and their GPA. When I run the program it says that in the ```if``` statement I am comparing an ```int``` and a ```std::vector<Student>::size_type```.

Comment: that should be *just* a warning, but there is more wrong in the code. Please include the compiler warnings/errors in the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Then how do I access the GetGPA() function without the program throwing an error on compilation, which is what it is doing to me right now.

Comment: I just edited the comment with a quick hack fix

Comment: @user4581301 That did it! Thank you so much. That had me stumped for a long time and I knew the solution wasn't that hard. Thanks again.

Comment: @user4581301 With the learning program that I am using for my class, this lab is very limited in what I can change outside of what I have done? Also, I edited my code and initialized ```probCount``` with the value of 0. Thanks again so much for the help.

Comment: @CritAnnihilation Please note that it is not, in general, helpful to edit your question to include fixes suggested in the comments or answers.  It just confuses future readers.  Instead, you can reply in the comments or post an answer to your own question.

Comment: If you don't go with the range-based `for` loop suggested by Paul  below, the warning about the different types can be fixed with `for (size_t i=0; i < roster.size(); ++i)`. `size_t` is an unsigned integer large enough to represent the size of any possible object.. Technically you should use `std::vector<Student>::size_type`, but I find that too verbose and more than a little pedantic.

Comment: Agree with @paul . Most of that edit is a great improvement or I'd roll it back. Instead I'm just going to spot-revert the two question-changing changes.

Comment: Side note, since you got the different signed-ness waring, you have some extra compiler warnings turned on. Another trick you can use to get the compiler to take a closer look at the code and find more mistakes is to turn on optimization. By adding `-O3` to the compiler options, I also get *warning: 'probCount' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]*.

Comment: The reason this happens is when optimizing, the compiler takes a much longer, closer look at the code trying to find ways to make it faster and this increased scrutiny allows it to spot things it misses, like an uninitialized variable, with the quicker, unoptimized builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop (as it was coded in the original question, before it was edited):

```
for (int i=1; i < roster.size(); ++i) {
   if (Student.GetGPA() < 2.0) {
      probCount = probCount + 1;
   }
}
```

is flawed for three reasons:

- `i` should start from 0, rather than 1
- `i` should be of type `size_t`, rather than `int`
- `Student` is a type, not a variable

A nice way to solve all these problems is to use a [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), like this:

```
for (Student &student : roster)
{
    if (student.GetGPA() < 2.0)
         probCount = probCount + 1;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, you also need to initialise `probCount` to zero before entering the loop:

```
int probCount = 0;
```

Finally, it's worth noting that the above loop would normally be coded as:

```
for (const Student &student : roster)
{
    ...
```

but that won't work here as `GetGPA` is not declared as a `const` method.  Thanks to @user4581301 for pointing this out.